# Manipulating sfml Vertex Array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sfml

I am doing research on the sfml Vertex Array functions.Based on this tutorial I've been introduced to a basic implementation and am wanting to add to it. Unfortunately I am relatively new at OOP and would appreciate any help adding to this.
The output generates a checkerboard like pattern using a sprite grid.

My goal is to connect the grid-floor tiles using a pathfinding algorithm(recursive bactracker) to generate a path.

the rest of this part is instantiated in the main.cpp:

```
//load the texture for our background vertex array
Texture textureBackground;
textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background_sheet.png");
```

once in the game loop as:

```
                //pass the vertex array by reference to the createBackground function
            int tileSize = createBackground(background, arena);
```

and finally in the draw scene:

```
        window.draw(background, &textureBackground);

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "zArena.h"

int createBackground(VertexArray& rVA, IntRect arena)
{
    // Anything we do to rVA we are actually doing to background (in the main function)

    // How big is each tile/texture
    const int TILE_SIZE = 50;
    const int TILE_TYPES = 3;
    const int VERTS_IN_QUAD = 4;

    int worldWidth = arena.width / TILE_SIZE;
    int worldHeight = arena.height / TILE_SIZE;

    // What type of primitive are we using?
    rVA.setPrimitiveType(Quads);

    // Set the size of the vertex array
    rVA.resize(worldWidth * worldHeight * VERTS_IN_QUAD);

    // Start at the beginning of the vertex array
    int currentVertex = 0;

    for (int w = 0; w < worldWidth; w++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < worldHeight; h++)
        {
            // Position each vertex in the current quad
            rVA[currentVertex + 0].position = Vector2f(w * TILE_SIZE, h * TILE_SIZE);
            rVA[currentVertex + 1].position = Vector2f((w * TILE_SIZE) + TILE_SIZE, h * TILE_SIZE);
            rVA[currentVertex + 2].position = Vector2f((w * TILE_SIZE) + TILE_SIZE, (h * TILE_SIZE) + TILE_SIZE);
            rVA[currentVertex + 3].position = Vector2f((w * TILE_SIZE), (h * TILE_SIZE) + TILE_SIZE);

            // Define the position in the Texture to draw for current quad
            // Either mud, stone, grass or wall
            //if (h == 0 || h == worldHeight - 1 || w == 0 || w == worldWidth - 1)
            if ((h % 2 !=0)&& (w % 2 != 0))
            {
                // Use the wall texture
                rVA[currentVertex + 0].texCoords = Vector2f(0, 0 + TILE_TYPES * TILE_SIZE);
                rVA[currentVertex + 1].texCoords = Vector2f(TILE_SIZE, 0 + TILE_TYPES * TILE_SIZE);
                rVA[currentVertex + 2].texCoords = Vector2f(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE + TILE_TYPES * TILE_SIZE);
                rVA[currentVertex + 3].texCoords = Vector2f(0, TILE_SIZE + TILE_TYPES * TILE_SIZE);
            }
            else
            {

                // Use a random floor texture
                srand((int)time(0) + h * w - h);
                int mOrG = (rand() % TILE_TYPES);
                int verticalOffset = mOrG * TILE_SIZE;
                //int verticalOffset = 0;

                rVA[currentVertex + 0].texCoords = Vector2f(0, 0 + verticalOffset);
                rVA[currentVertex + 1].texCoords = Vector2f(TILE_SIZE, 0 + verticalOffset);
                rVA[currentVertex + 2].texCoords = Vector2f(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE + verticalOffset);
                rVA[currentVertex + 3].texCoords = Vector2f(0, TILE_SIZE + verticalOffset);

            }

            // Position ready for the next for vertices
            currentVertex = currentVertex + VERTS_IN_QUAD;
        }
    }

    return TILE_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix logic and rendering parts. As such, vertex arrays should have nothing to do with how your path algorithm works.

Comment: I'm relatively new to this library and  as such I use the library to the best of my knowledge.So now I'm looking for alternatives to my approach.My issue is that I am struggling to build the tile engine in a way to satisfy these components.Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see, there you're generating your tiles *on the fly*. If you want to create something like a *walkable* space, you should generate your tile map first, and then draw it based on the content generated.

Maybe *overkilling* your question, there are several ways to [generate random maps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79049/generating-tile-map)  satisfying specific constraints.

When you have the choice done, then you can simply draw as you do, but instead of

```
// Use a random floor texture
            srand((int)time(0) + h * w - h);
            int mOrG = (rand() % TILE_TYPES);
            int verticalOffset = mOrG * TILE_SIZE;
```

should have something like

```
// Select texture rect based on generated tilemap
            int mOrG = tilemap[w][h];    // Or tilemap[h * worldWidth + w] if you do it as unidimensional array
            int verticalOffset = mOrG * TILE_SIZE;
```

With this approach you must pass tilemap to your render method or, even better, create a TileMap class overriding `draw()` method